# Couchbase & ElasticSearch Replication on Vagrant Box

Tags: elasticsearch, vagrant, couchbase, vagrantfile

I have successfully setup couchbase and elasticsearch on my machine, and configured the XDCR (cross datacenter replication) without a problem. Now, however I am trying to achieve the same setup on a vagrant box. I have elasticsearch and couchbase running without a problem, and port forwarding setup so I can access the couchbase admin console from my browser.

When I try and setup the replication though I get the following error

```
Error {econnrefused,[{lhttpc_client,send_request,1}, {lhttpc_client,execute,9},
lhttpc_client,request,9}]} happened during REST call get to http://127.0.0.1:9091/pools.
```

I am setting up the replication with `IP/hostname 127.0.0.1:9091`, which is what worked when I was doing it locally, i.e. without vagrant. Could this be the problem? Since `localhost` isn't  referring to the vagrant machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, despite using versions of couchbase and elasticsearch that were supposed to be compatible, I decided to try the same approach with different versions, namely

```
couchbase-server-enterprise_2.5.1_x86_64.deb
elasticsearch-1.0.1.deb
elasticsearch-transport-couchbase-1.3.0
```

Instead of port forwarding in my Vagrant file I also made sure I was using a private network

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

and then when I attempted to setup replication using `192.168.33.10:9091` as the hostname it worked.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess you are trying to use the wrong port for replication - Couchbase uses port *8091* **not** *9091*.

Comment: Yes, but the Elasticsearch transport protocol is listening on 9091, which is the destination. These values worked perfectly before I brought Vagrant in

Comment: Have you checked your firewall settings?